# Operation not permitted при удалении папки

Tags: node.js, файлы, файловая-система, fs

Использую Puppeteer-firefox для работы с Firefox в headless режиме.

При запуске создаю профили для временного использования

Возникло решение удалять их после использования, код такой:

```
const path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs')

const profiles_temp_dir = path.join(__dirname, '/app/temp');
//Чистим профили Firefox
fs.readdir(profiles_temp_dir, (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  for (const file of files) {
    fs.unlink(path.join(profiles_temp_dir, file), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
});
```

Но в итоге получаю:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Github\MyApp\app\temp'
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Решения не нашел, есть только подобные проблемы с `npm install`

Comment: А FF вообще закрыт в это время? Хотя, вроде тогда бы EACCESS было...

Comment: Я тоже думал что что то использует папку в данный момент, но все закрыто, а FF даже собственно еще не открывался, данный код запускается в самом начале скрипта, за долго до запуска FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты пытаешься через `unlink` удалять и файлы, и каталоги. Но согласно документации так удалять можно только файлы и символьные ссылки, а для каталогов надо использовать `rmdir`. Кстати, есть подозрение, что каталог должен быть пустым...

Comment: Хмм, спасибо. Странно что Operation not permitted, а не что то вроде directory is not empty

Comment: @RedWoolf, так этот метод вообще с папками не работает.